# Why do I need to have anonymous function in the setTimeout for this code to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading a tutorial for Nodejs, but I can't understand this snippet of code, please explain it to me.

```
function async(arg, callback) {
  console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);
}
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }

var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var results = [];
var running = 0;
var limit = 2;

function launcher() {
  while(running < limit && items.length > 0) {
    var item = items.shift();
    async(item, function(result) {
      results.push(result);
      running--;
      if(items.length > 0) {
        launcher();
      } else if(running == 0) {
        final();
      }
    });
    running++;
  }
}

launcher();
```

This code produces run 2x then pause for a second then run 2x again until there is no item in the items array.

But when I removed the anonymous function in the setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(callback(arg*2), 1000);
```

Then the code runs with out stopping any second. Why?

Comment: Why it stops running without waiting a second ? Because the setTimeout causes the 1 second "wait" and you removed it.

Comment: i removed the anonymous function, but the settimeout still calls the callback(arg*2) in 1 second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then the code runs with out stopping any second. Why?

Because instead of passing a function to `setTimeout`, you are passing the return value of a function *call* to it.

The function call executes immediately, and then `setTimeout` does nothing with the return value because it (presumably) isn't a string or a function.

**Don't** remove the anonymous function wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the anonymous delegate is needed is because setTimeout expects an object of type `function` as it's first argument.

So you can either give it just a pre-defined function name directly:

```
function foo()
{
//do something
}

setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Or a delegate:

```
setTimeout(function(){/*dosomething*/}, 1000);
```

But this:

```
setTimeout(foo(param), 1000);
```

Is invalid because foo(param) isn't semantically correct in this context.

The alternative is to do something like:

```
setTimeout("foo(param);", 1000);
```

Because setTimeout will also accept a string of a function, but this is a bad idea because you lose the current scope and it's a pain to debug.

Comment: Never pass a string to `setTimeout`. It gets evaled, is slow, is hard to debug and breaks scope.

Comment: The question is asking why it is needed. That code appears in the original question.

Comment: `foo(param)` is syntactically correct, and given `function foo(bar) { return function () { alert(bar); }; }` it will work.

Comment: Yes, it's *syntactically* correct (it's legal JS), it's just not *semantically* correct (it computes a nonsensical result).